# Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'addUtilisateur' not found on type com.faycal.bean.UtilisateurBean

Tags: jsf-2, el

I've the below command button:

```
<h:commandButton value="Valider" action="#{utilisateurBean.addUtilisateur()}" />
```

When I click this button, an error appears in server log:

> Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'addUtilisateur' not found on type com.faycal.bean.UtilisateurBean

How is this caused and how can I solve it? The `UtilisateurBean` is `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: Did you use google translate to translate from French? Hard to understand what you are asking...

Comment: post your bean code and error message

Comment: public String addUtilisateur(){
  Utilisateur u = new Utilisateur();
  u.setDateInscription(new Date());
  return "/compte/add-utilisateur-result.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&resultat=ok";
 }

Comment: And error code :
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'addUtilisateur' not found on type com.faycal.bean.UtilisateurBean

Comment: What is the scope of `UtilisateurBean`? PS: In future please edit your question and don't post that much code in comments. makes it more readable ;)

Comment: I found the problem, in my jsp file, the tag of <form> must be changed to <h:form>